# update a row if already exists else insert

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE bonuses (employee_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100);
```

This create table query.

Datas to insert:

```
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES(111)
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES(112)
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES(113)
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES(114)
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES(115)
```

Trying into use merge query for either insert or update

```
merge into bonuses 
using( SELECT * FROM bonuses)s ON s.employee_id = 111   
WHEN MATCHED THEN update set bonus='555' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(116)
```

It should modify value of bonus where `employee_id=111`

I'm getting an error while executing this.
This is just sample table, I have created to test the `merge exec`.

Comment: `insert insert`??

Comment: "I'm getting an error while executing this. [But I don't tell you which, so I leave this as a puzzle for you and make it thus harder to help me]".

Comment: Yeah I`m getting an error, that is why I came for help

Comment: But *which* error? There must be an error message you are getting telling you what this error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very wrong. The `USING` clause is supposed to specify the source for the update/insert. So you are mainly saying "I want to update my bonuses with the data from my bonuses table". Accordingly for every record in the table you check whether to insert or update.

Use a dummy single source record instead. (And the `ON` clause in a `MERGE` requires parantheses.)

```
MERGE INTO bonuses 
USING (SELECT * FROM dual) s ON (bonuses.employee_id = 111)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET bonus = '555' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (employee_id) VALUES (116);
```

It's surprising though, that you don't set the bonus in the insert. (And it's also a rare case to check for one employee ID and if not present insert *another*.)

Here is a more typical query, but this only affects employee ID 111:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses 
USING (SELECT 111 as employee_id, 555 as bonus FROM dual) src 
   ON (bonuses.employee_id = src.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET bonus = src.bonus
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (employee_id, bonus) VALUES (src.employee_id, src.bonus);
```

Comment: pls give me merge query or any other way to insert or update if exits, I can`t use select count if already exists because there are lot of such queries in my real scenario procedure, it is not possible to select count.

Comment: I don't understand. You want a `MERGE` statement. I've corrected yours. What does this have to do with `COUNT`?

Comment: instead of counting the match  of row already exists and going for insert or update, I`ve gone for merge.

Comment: Okay. I've corrected your `MERGE` statement. Does it work for you? If not, how is it not working for you?

Comment: I`m facing  some network issues here, so I couldn`t check now, I`ll update soon. Thanks for your help..

Comment: Error starting at line : 3 in command -
MERGE INTO bonuses 
USING (SELECT * FROM dual) s ON (bonuses.employee_id = 111)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET bonus = '555' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (116)
Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 30
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
00926. 00000 -  "missing VALUES keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: This is for the second query  
Error starting at line : 8 in command -
MERGE INTO bonuses 
USING (SELECT 111 as employee_id, 555 as bonus FROM dual) src 
   ON (bonuses.employee_id = src.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET bonus = src.bonus
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id, bonus)
                                   VALUES (src.employee_id, src.bonus)
Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 30
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
00926. 00000 -  "missing VALUES keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Sorry there was a `INTO bonuses` too many in the insert syntax. (I should better have written the statements from scratch rather then copy, paste and alter yours :-) I've corrected my queries.

Comment: You are welcome. Next time, for the mere Syntax, look up the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606